# Getting a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I´m pretty new at python , cant seem to get this code to work , getting a "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str," --help please ! Thanks a ton

```
import pandas as pd 
from glob import glob
filenames = glob('abc*.xls')
df3 =[pd.read_excel(f) for f in filenames]
df4 = df3[df3['Unnamed: 11'].str.contains("tele", na=False)]
```

Comment: The code ```df3['Unnamed: 11'].str.contains("tele", na=False)``` will return you a boolean series but df3 being a list expects integer index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `df3` is `list of DataFrames`, because created by list comprehension.

So you can join all DataFrames together if possible:

```
df3 =[pd.read_excel(f) for f in filenames]
df33 = pd.concat(df3, ignore_index=True)
df4 = df33[df33['Unnamed: 11'].str.contains("tele", na=False)]
```

Another idea is processing each DataFrame separately:

```
for df in df3:
    df4 = df3[df3['Unnamed: 11'].str.contains("tele", na=False)]
    ...
    ...
```